# Correctly calculate bounding box for a transformed rectangle with System.Numerics

Tags: c#, vector-graphics, bounding-box

I'm using the following algorithm to calculate the bounding box for a transformed rectangle but it seems to have issues.

```
public static Rectangle GetBoundingRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, Matrix3x2 matrix)
{
    Vector2 leftTop = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top), matrix);
    Vector2 rightTop = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Top), matrix);
    Vector2 leftBottom = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom), matrix);
    Vector2 rightBottom = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom), matrix);

    Vector2 min = Vector2.Min(Vector2.Min(leftTop, rightTop), Vector2.Min(leftBottom, rightBottom));
    Vector2 max = Vector2.Max(Vector2.Max(leftTop, rightTop), Vector2.Max(leftBottom, rightBottom));

    return new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(max.X - min.X), (int)(max.Y - min.Y));
}
```

It works well with rotation but not with skew. As you will can see from the images below the rectangle calculated from the formula is too small. Can anyone spot what the issue is or is there a method already within the `System.Numerics` namespace that I can use?

Rotate - Matrix formula

```
Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(radians, origin)
```

[image: Rotated image with correct bounding box]

Skew - Matrix formula

```
Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(radiansX, radiansY, origin)
```

[image: Skewed image with incorrect bounding box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is with what you've done but it isn't representing the most robust definition of the bounding box which is this:

```
var allCorners = new List<Vector2> { leftTop, rightTop, leftBottom, rightBottom };
var xExtent = allCorners.Select(v => v.X).Max() - allCorners.Select(v => v.X).Min();
var yExtent = allCorners.Select(v => v.Y).Max() - allCorners.Select(v => v.Y).Min();
return new Rectangle(0, 0, xExtent, yExtent);
```

Comment: I think we are both returning the same result which matches a JavaScript test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/53302x4w/embedded/) So I think the formula might actually be correct. Oddly it just doesn't seem big enough.